# How can I justify my text in a table?

Tags: tables

Can you please help me "flushing left" the text inside the table´s first column ?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Atividade} & \multirow{2}{*}{Precedência} &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Duração (\textit{semanas})}\\ \cline{3-4} 
&&Média&Desvio padrão\\ \hline
\textbf{A} - Fundações & -& 3& 0.6 \\ \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{B} - Processo de recrutamento & -& 5& 1.4\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{C} - Canalizações & A & 2 & 0.45\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{D} - Estrutura do edifício& A& 4 & 0.7\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{E} - Pavimento e teto& C, D & 2 & 0.4\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{F} - Construção de áreas internas&  E& 5 & 0.5\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{G} - Instalação do sistema elétrico& F& 0.5& 0.3\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{H} - Instalação de equipamentos& F& 3 & 0.2\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{I} - Formação de funcionários& B, F  & 2 & 0.1\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{J} - Establecimento de parcerias locais& B& 3& 0.8\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
\textbf{K} - Fase de teste & G, H, I& 1 & 0.1\\  \hline
```

\end{tabular}

[image]

Comment: You must replace the first "c" here \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} for an L on minusc -> l
\begin{tabular}{| l |c|c|c|}

Comment: What if I want to maintain my 1st row "Atividade" in the center?

Comment: @davids_73 please have a look at the answer if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Atividade}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Precedência} 
     &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Duração (\textit{semanas})}\\ \cline{3-4} 
    &&Média&Desvio padrão\\ \hline
    \textbf{A} - Fundações & -& 3& 0.6 \\ \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{B} - Processo de recrutamento & -& 5& 1.4\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{C} - Canalizações & A & 2 & 0.45\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{D} - Estrutura do edifício& A& 4 & 0.7\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{E} - Pavimento e teto& C, D & 2 & 0.4\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{F} - Construção de áreas internas&  E& 5 & 0.5\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{G} - Instalação do sistema elétrico& F& 0.5& 0.3\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{H} - Instalação de equipamentos& F& 3 & 0.2\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{I} - Formação de funcionários& B, F  & 2 & 0.1\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{J} - Establecimento de parcerias locais& B& 3& 0.8\\  \Xhline{0.008pt}
    \textbf{K} - Fase de teste & G, H, I& 1 & 0.1\\  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

**To avoid verticals**

[image]

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%<-----------------------add to preamble
```

%%%%%%%%%

```
 \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}

\begin{tabular}{lccc}\toprule[2pt]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-1}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!25}Atividade}} & 
         \multirow{-1}{*}{\cellco lor{gray!25}Precedência} &
             \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{green!50}Duração 
                                                    (\textit{semanas})}\\ 
                          &   &\cellcolor{green!25}--Média-- 
                                  &\cellcolor{green!25}--Desvio padrão--\\ 
    \textbf{A} - Fundações & -& 3& 0.6 \\
    \textbf{B} - Processo de recrutamento & -& 5& 1.4\\  
    \textbf{C} - Canalizações & A & 2 & 0.45\\  
    \textbf{D} - Estrutura do edifício& A& 4 & 0.7\\
    \textbf{E} - Pavimento e teto& C, D & 2 & 0.4\\ 
    \textbf{F} - Construção de áreas internas&  E& 5 & 0.5\\
    \textbf{G} - Instalação do sistema elétrico& F& 0.5& 0.3\\
    \textbf{H} - Instalação de equipamentos& F& 3 & 0.2\\  
    \textbf{I} - Formação de funcionários& B, F  & 2 & 0.1\\
    \textbf{J} - Establecimento de parcerias locais& B& 3& 0.8\\
    \textbf{K} - Fase de teste & G, H, I& 1 & 0.1\\  \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thank you once again ahahah ! it worked